# Styling <select> Tag in IF IE 7 statement

Tags: css, select, internet-explorer-7, if-statement

I realize that IE is not as friendly with CSS styles on the  dropdown in a form. On a page I am building here: 
http://vpointproductions.com/html-code/clinique-css.html

I am trying to fix the  dropdowns to be the same height in IE7 as it appears in FF, Saf, and Chrome. However, the image I am using in the CSS to make it work in those browsers is still appearing in IE 7. I am trying to include an if statement for IE 7 to fix this issue but I am having no luck. The CSS i am using is here:
http://vpointproductions.com/html-code/clinique-stylesheet.css

Comment: Note that neither CSS nor HTML make many provisions about styling form controls. In IE's case up to IE 7 `select` was no lightweight control and thus cannot be styled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **conditional comments** for targeting just IE7

```
<!--[if IE 7]>

    //place your styles here or a link to an IE7 stylesheet

<![endif]-->
```

Place this in the head of your document.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks jason. i actually already have the conditional statement in my header for other IE fixes. my only real issue is styling the select box in IE 7. it looks and works great everywhere else, including IE 8. I just cant get the dropdown to look right in IE 7.

Comment: Gotcha.  Any screenshots you could share?  I looked in Chrome and IE7 and I am not seeing a difference?